# How to display Current Geolocation Coords in Xamarin without a <Button/>?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a simple form with button who get current geolocation coords and display on two labels.

The code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{   
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

            if (location == null)
            {
                location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest()
                {
                    DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                });
            }
            if (location == null)
            {
                LabelLocation.Text = "No GPS";
            }
            else
            {
                LabelLocation.Text = $"{location.Latitude} {location.Longitude}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Something is wrong : {ex.Message}");
        }

    }
}
```

So the method on Button is async.. I want to move the code from the button under **InitializeComponent();**

I want when app start to display geolocation coords on the labels without click on the button.

I try to move the code from the button under **InitializeComponent();** but I see this error message: [image: Error]

So.. How to move the code from Button_Clicked in the constructor ?

I try to remove await in the constructor like that:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            var location =  Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

            if (location == null)
            {
                location =  Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest()
                {
                    DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                });
            }
            if (location == null)
            {
                LabelLocation.Text = "No GPS";
            }
            else
            {
                LabelLocation.Text = $"{location.Latitude} {location.Longitude}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Something is wrong : {ex.Message}");
        }

    }
```

But I receive this error message: CS1061 [image: after remove await]

Comment: location = Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest()
                {
                    DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                }).Result ;

Comment: When I remove await I have issue on this line:  else
                {
                    LabelLocation.Text = $"{location.Latitude} {location.Longitude}";
                } The error is: CS1061

Comment: but .Result; at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your code in the `OnAppearing` event

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: OP, please use the comment feature to ask additional questions.  Do not edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create another async method like `private async string GetUserLocationAsync()` and put your code in there. Then call that method right after `InitializeComponent()`